# How do I set StyleUrls with variable in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a `ts` file like this

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  profile : './test/test.css'
};
```

I would like to import `environment.profile` and set it so that I can use it in the StyleUrls like

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from "@ngx-translate/core";
import {environment} from "../../environments/environment";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: [environment.profile]
})
```

But I am getting the error:

> Error: Cannot find module "."  main.bundle.js:250:62
>     webpackMissingModule http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:250:62
>     ../../../../../src/app/header/header.component.ts
>   http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:250:29   **webpack_require**
>   http://localhost:4200/inline.bundle.js:55:12
>     ../../../../../src/app/app.module.ts
>   http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:71:83    **webpack_require**
>   http://localhost:4200/inline.bundle.js:55:12
>     ../../../../../src/main.ts
>   http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:291:74   **webpack_require**
>   http://localhost:4200/inline.bundle.js:55:12  [2]
>   http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:309:18   **webpack_require**
>   http://localhost:4200/inline.bundle.js:55:12  webpackJsonpCallback
>   http://localhost:4200/inline.bundle.js:26:23  
>   http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:1:1 [WDS] Warnings while
>   compiling.  vendor.bundle.js:13428:10
>   ./src/app/header/header.component.ts 32:17-45 Critical dependency: the
>   request of a dependency is an expression  vendor.bundle.js:13493:4

I don't know how to fix it can someone help me

Answer (score 0):

Its because of the value of your variable `environment.profile`.

Please see whether it refers to the exact path of your css **OR** give path of styleUrl as String.

Please correct me if I have misinterpreted your question.

---------------------UPDATE--------------------

According to the discussion in the comments, I just suggest to use the approach based on the class and not the Const.

Because the Const doesn't return anything when called in constructor of the component and does return correct value in ngOnInit().

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uq4kLWPfosU

Here is the video link to new boston's tutorial of Angular which I referred. There he uses a class named `Config` to store various details such as *MAIN_HEADING* etc..

So according to me, that will be a cleaner approach to solve your problem.

Comment: it refers to the exact path of my css

Comment: Can you try to put a hard coded string instead of the variable? ( Just for confirmation about what the problem is )

Comment: it imported but i it isn't showing in my example code i will change it

Comment: And one last thing, what is the output of console.log(environment) in constructor call?

Comment: in the component constructor is empty but it has value in the ngOnInit Object { production: false, profile: "./test/test.css" }

Comment: I guess its because of this that youre facing the error. Why shall it be blank in the constructor. I have seen this approach and usually what they do is they make a service to store such variables and inject the service to use the variables.. I guess you wanna give a try to that too.

Comment: Can you give my an example?

Comment: And I m sorry, it wasn't service, it was simply a class and not a const.

Comment: Alright.. can you make a plunker and put a link in your question so that I can test it?

Answer (score 0):

I am fighting the same problem.

Basically, you cannot use an expression directly in your styleUrls, this is what this log is telling you.

> Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
>   vendor.bundle.js:13493:4

To fix it, you may use interpolation in a string inside styleUrls, like this.

```
@Component {
  ……
  styleUrls: `${environment.profile}`
}
```

Beware though, my investigation stops at this variable being interpreted as a wildcard, and therefore mapping all the file at the same level of the variabl inside your `main.js`.

I'll update my answer if I can solde the wildcard issue!